# Angular noob: Why is my homepage not loading (routes related)?

Tags: angularjs

This is my first time playing with Angular.js. I have an index page:

```
<html ng-app="toDoListApp">
<head>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.css"/>
</head>
<body>
    {{ 1+2 }} #<-- this part is breaking

    <div class="main" ng-view></div>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0-beta.5/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/routes.js"></script>
    <script src="js/services.js"></script>
    <script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
    <script src="js/filters.js"></script>
    <script src="js/directives.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm trying to get my routes to work with it. Here's my routes.js:

```
var toDoListApp = angular.module('toDoListApp', []);


/////////////////////////////
//when I remove this bottom part, the index.html page works.
toDoListApp.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when(
        '/',
        {
            templateUrl: 'partials/chores.html',
            controller: 'ChoresController'
        });
});

///////////////////////////////
```

Not too sure what I'm doing wrong... Am I missing a dependency? Here's my package.json file that I copied from the angular website tutorial:

```
{
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "name": "toDoListApp",
  "description": "fooling around with angular",
  "devDependencies": {
    "karma": "~0.10",
    "protractor": "~0.20.1",
    "http-server": "^0.6.1",
    "bower": "^1.3.1",
    "shelljs": "^0.2.6"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "postinstall": "bower install",

    "start": "http-server -p 8000",
    "test": "karma start test/karma.conf.js",

    "update-webdriver": "webdriver-manager update",
    "protractor": "protractor test/protractor-conf.js",
    "test-single-run": "karma start test/karma.conf.js --single-run",

    "update-index-async": "node -e \"require('shelljs/global'); sed('-i', /\\/\\/@@NG_LOADER_START@@[\\s\\S]*\\/\\/@@NG_LOADER_END@@/, '//@@NG_LOADER_START@@\\n' + cat('bower_components/angular-loader/angular-loader.min.js') + '\\n//@@NG_LOADER_END@@', 'app/index-async.html');\""
  }
}
```

and my bower.json also from angular's tutorial:

```
{
  "name": "toDoListApp",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "angular": "1.2.x",
    "angular-mocks": "~1.2.15",
    "bootstrap": "~3.1.1",
    "angular-route": "~1.2.15",
    "angular-resource": "~1.2.15",
    "jquery": "1.10.2",
    "angular-animate": "~1.2.15"
  }
}
```

Let me know if you need any more files.

=== **UPDATE** ===

The log seems to have changed after I added ngRoutes, but my controller is having issues:

INDEX.HTML

```
<html ng-app="toDoListApp">
<head>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.css"/>
</head>
<body>
    {{ 1+2 }} #<-- still breaks

    <div class="main" ng-view></div>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0-beta.5/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0-beta.5/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/routes.js"></script>
    <script src="js/services.js"></script>
    <script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
    <script src="js/filters.js"></script>
    <script src="js/directives.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Routes:

```
var toDoListApp = angular.module('toDoListApp', ['ngRoute']);

toDoListApp.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when(
        '/',
        {
            templateUrl: 'partials/chores.html',
            controller: 'ChoresController'
        });
})];
```

But in the log it now says it's a syntax error in my controller:

```
toDoListApp.controller("ChoresController", function($scope) {
    $scope.chores = ["laundry", "dishes"];
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ngRoute in AngularJS is not included with the library.

You can download it via Google's CDN

https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0-beta.5/angular-route.min.js

Load it just after AngularJS.

You also need to specify it as a dependency for your app's module.

```
var toDoListApp = angular.module('toDoListApp', ['ngRoute']);
```

When configuring your routes. You have to inject the $routeProvider

```
toDoListApp.config(['$routePrivder',function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when(
        '/',
        {
            templateUrl: 'partials/chores.html',
            controller: 'ChoresController'
        });
}]);
```

Route controllers are used to handle special logic when changing routes. Don't confuse a route controller with a controller you would use with a directive.

Comment: still didn't work... i'll update my question with everything i did

Answer (score 0):

I haven't always had success using `controller` within my routes. So instead, I've opted for just setting the controller in the view itself.

```
<div ng-controller="ChoresController">

</div>
```

Comment: A route controller, and a view controller are not the same thing. A route controller is specific to controlling a route. It is called after the template is created for the route.

Comment: hmm, so maybe that's part of the issue I had been having with my implementation.

Comment: I guess I'm not sure of the use case for it. Why would you need to load a controller after a view has been loaded?

Comment: maybe. If your route does nothing more then load a template, then maybe all it needs is an empty controller function. The template should use directives to load what code it depends upon.

Comment: I use controllers in routes to read the parameters from the URL, and assign state information to my services. For example; a blog might read the current category from the URL and set the breadcrumb service to that category.

Comment: Oh interesting. Ya, I've just been adding things like that in the view controller, ha. It may be time for some refactoring.